# Nixos: how to fix network gateway when nixos-rebuild requires network

Tags: nixos

I changed ISP, and the new router they gave me does not have the same IP as the old one (192.168.1.1 vs 192.168.1.254)

I had statically configured 192.168.1.1 as the default gateway on my Nixos, so now I can ssh to it but it can't connect to anything by itself.

I tried fixing the configuration and doing a `nixos-rebuild`, but it tries to download some files.

I read https://discourse.nixos.org/t/rebuild-nixos-offline/3679/4 but it isn't very helpful.

How can I apply this gateway change with my broken network connectivity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ip route del default && ip route add default via 192.168.1.254 dev eth0` allowed me to get the network working and do a proper `nixos-rebuild switch --fast`

Answer (score 0):

If your NixOS uses NetworkManager, you can fix your network by `nmtui` or `nmcli`. Then, you can run `nixos-rebuild`.